# Ordering gauges within single Grafana panel

Tags: statistics, grafana

I have created a panel with 6 LogQL queries (shown below), calculating basic stats on a given dataset (min, percentiles, etc..). I want to order the gages so they have a logical ordering, and make it easy to visualize.

For instance the panel below would be a lot easier to read if it was presenting each gauge in the following order:
min, p50, p75, p99, max, stddev.

As of now the order is just random and will change after each page reload. Any way I could get the ordering I am looking for?

[image]